# Overriding file_image model in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to change the image quality for products in my Magento (1.5.10) store.

After much research, I found a forum post that shows how, with a small change to one of the Magento core files. Since changing the core is BAD, I am trying to override the File_Image model using a custom module.

I created the following files:

1. /app/etc/modules/Quantumco_Image.xml http://pastie.org/private/ucqbcwsqassv56njsdyona
2. /app/code/local/Quantumco/Image/etc/config.xml http://pastie.org/private/aq2pnlaohtbtjvikzeftg
3. /app/code/local/Quantumco/Image/Model/Image.php http://pastie.org/private/li7tgoqhlnyyf7mpc0eg8g

My module is being loaded (it shows as being enabled in the admin backend), but my code does not seem to be actually overriding the Model. As far as I can tell, Image.php isn't running at all.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to override this model?

---

*update* changed Config.xml to config.xml as suggested

*update* Using my "break the file to see if its being included" technique, I have figured out that my config.xml file is not being parsed. Any ideas what might cause that?

*update* In the end, it seems like I had a plugin conflict. I think.

Comment: Is it really `Quantumco/Image/etc/Config.xml` or `config.xml`?

Comment: @nachito Yes, it really is Config.xml

Comment: I think that's your problem then. Change it to `config.xml`.

Comment: @nachito done, no noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

`quantumco_image` should be `Quantumco_Image` in your nodes of `config.xml` as well as nachito mentioned keeping it lowercase are best practices.

Also take a look at Mage_Media/etc/config.xml and follow the node paths to the model you want to rewrite.

I believe your wanting to rewrite media_file, instead of media.

```
<global>
<models>
<media_file>
<rewrite>
<image>Quantumco_Image_Model_Image</image>
</rewrite>
</media_file>
</models>
</global>
```

Comment: Also, checkout http://codemagento.com/2011/02/rewriting-a-model-class/ is a better example than the inchoo article.

Comment: Made the changes, but it still doesn't seem to be working. I'll check out that article.